# If i know that $f(x)$ is Riemann-integrable, can I conclude something about the value of a sequence of Riemann sums of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

I want to calculate the limit of $S_n=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k^2}{n^3}=\frac{1}{n}\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k^2}{n^2}$
My idea is to interpretate $S_n$ as a sequence of Riemann sums of $f(x)=x^2$, becaus I know that
$\int \limits_{0}^{b}x^2dx=\frac{b^3}{3  }$ or rather $f$ is Riemann integrable because $f$ is continous.

Define $\xi_{n,k}=\frac{bk}{n}=x_{n,k}$.For the partition $P_n=(x_{n,0},x_{n,1},...,x_{n,n})$ then follows: $|P|=\max\lbrace x_{n,k}-x_{n,k-1}|k\leq n \rbrace = \frac{b}{n}\rightarrow 0$.

I conclude ( probably wrongly) that:
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} S(f,P_n,\xi_{n})=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}f(\xi_{n,k})(x_{n,k}-x_{n,k-1})=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^2}{n^2}\frac{1}{n}=\int \limits_{0}^{b}x^2=\frac{b^3}{3 }$
because every sequence of Riemann sums to a Riemann integrable function $f$ has to convert against the same value. I summarize:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k^2}{n^3}=\frac{1}{b}\int \limits_{0}^{b}x^2dx=\frac{b^2}{3}$$

Is that correct? It seems wrong, because the value of the series would depend on $b$

### Edit

I changed
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^2}{n^3}$ to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k^2}{n^3}$.

Note: If you downvote my question, please leave a comment with a brief explanation so I can learn from possible mistakes.

Comment: $$\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^n f \left(a + k \dfrac{b - a}{n} \right) \to \int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$
In your case $a = 0$ and $b = 1$.

Comment: Note that $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^2}{n^3}\neq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k^2}{n^3}$. The former is infinite, while the latter is equal to $\int_0^1 x^2\; dx = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: $\xi_{n,k}=\frac{bk}{n}$ and $f(x) = x^2$, so $f(\xi_{n,k}) = \frac{b^2k^2}{n^2} $ and $S(f,P_n,\xi_{n}) = \frac{b^3}{n^3} \sum_k k^2$.